# Javascript - find multiple number values in table cell and convert from cm to inches

Tags: javascript, html, regex, loops, dom

I have this HTML table: https://jsfiddle.net/wt8dnkor/

What I try to do is to loop over all  elements - all table cell, find if there is string 'cm' and if yes then to convert a value from cm to inches.

So I write this code:

```
var allDivTd = document.getElementById("sizeadviser_content").getElementsByTagName("TD");

for(var i = 0; i < allDivTd.length; i++){
    var td = allDivTd[i];
    if (td.innerText.includes("cm") === true) {
        //td.innerText = td.innerText+' in';
    }
}
```

So as you can see I want to change only cells where the string contains 'cm'.

How to get number values from the cell and convert them to inches using 1 decimal?

The problem is because I dont know how many number values are in cell. They could be in format like `20cm or 20-50cm or 20 - 50 cm or 20 | 50 cm` ... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that should work for decimal values:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allDivTd.length; i++) {
  var td = allDivTd[i];    
  if (td.innerText.includes("cm") === true) {

    new_td = td.innerText.replace('cm', '').replaceAll(' ', '');
    for (let char of new_td) {

      if (isNaN(char) && char != ".") {
        new_td = new_td.replace(char, ",").split(',');
        new_td.forEach(function(centim, index, myArray) {

          myArray[index] = (centim * 0.393701).toFixed(2);
        });

        new_td = new_td.toString().replace(',', ' - ') + ' in'

        td.innerText = new_td;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a very fast solution, you can use something like this

```
function setStr(str) {
  let digit = '';
  let newStr = ''; 
  for (let char of str) {

    if (!isNaN(char)) {
      digit += char;
    } else {
      newStr +=  converter(digit)+ char;
      digit = '';
    }
 }
 return newStr.replace('cm', 'in');
}

function converter(s) {
  if (s) {
    return (parseInt(s)*0.393707).toString();
  }
  return '';
}
```

or using regex

```
 function parseString(str) {
   var matcher = /\D+/;
   var list = str.split(matcher);
   list.forEach((item) => {
     if (item) {
       str = str.replace(item, (parseInt(item)*0.393707).toString()); 
     } 
   });
   return str.replace('cm', 'in');
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very good just string like "96 - 104 cm" returns me like "37.8-40.9 in" ... so spaces are not there

Comment: Sorry just your code do not work well with decimal values

Comment: Do you need to save spaces too?

Answer (score 1):

i think u could use the regx by using split(/\D+/)

check my example

```js
    function gtnmbrs () {
        var strng = '50 - 10 | 555 cm';
        var nonnmbrs = /\D+/;
        var rslt = strng.split(nonnmbrs);
        for (i=0; i<rslt.length; i++) {   
       document.write("<p>"+rslt[i]*0.39370+" inch</p>");
       }
}
```

```html
<p>Convert to:</p>
    <input type="button" id="bt" value="Click it!" onclick="gtnmbrs()"/>
```

check out this snippet it could help u to get out the numbers only, then convert it from cm to inch

Comment: Sorry just your code do not work well with decimal values